In MATLAB, after removing some elements, how can the original matrix remain a matrix instead of becoming a row vector?
For example:
A = [0 0 0;0 2 2];
A(1:2)=[]

A=
   0 2 0 2

How to make A become [0 2; 0 2], and not [0 2 0 2] after deleting process? Why is the result is 0 2 0 2?

Wouldn't the result be [0 0; 2 2]? You're deleting the first column.

@beaker A(1:2) is the first column?

Yes. It's linear indices 1 and 2, which gives the first two elements in the first column. A(1:3) would be the first column and the first element in column 2.

@beaker May you test it? I feel it is in the first row.

I did. Before I commented. Would you like to test it? A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6], A(1:2)

@beaker  I guess A(1:2) returns the first two elements in the first row.

Cool, let me know how that works out for you.

When you use a single index into the matrix, you explicitly convert the matrix to a 1D array.
Instead, use two indices:
A(:,1) = [];

